# How to attach click event to an element inside my jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a plugin and need to allow the end user to be able to take control of a click event being invoked from inside the plugin.

How would I go about achieving that? I've so far worked upto this point:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.multiForm = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            titles : [],
            nextButton: 'nl-next',
            prevButton: 'nl-prev',
            onNext: function(){}
        }, options);

        //#1 I first need to attach a click event on settings.nextButton element
        //#2 So when that button is clicked, I want the user to use oNext() and return true or false which I will then capture inside this plugin

        this.each( function(options) {  
            // some plugin code 
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

This is how the user will use the plugin:

```
$('#someID').multiForm({
   onNext:function(){
     // return either true or false
     // I need to capture this return value
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your plugin, you can call `settings.onNext` and use its return value.

```
if(typeof settings.onNext === 'function') {
   var result = settings.onNext();
   if(result) { ... }
}
```

You attach a click event to the `nextButton` like you would with any other button:

```
$(setting.nextButton).click(function() { 
   ...
});
```

Note that `nl-next` is not a valid jQuery selector. Is it a class name? If so, make sure to add `.` to the selector.

Also note that you may want to pass some context, to make sure that you don't add the listener to all buttons of this class, in case there are several instances of your plugin on the page.

```
$('.' + setting.nextButton, someDivWrappingMyPlugin).click(function() {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Cool. But I updated my question while you were about to post it. I also need to attach a click event on an element

Comment: @asprin: I've updated my answer. Adding click listeners in a plugin is no different from adding them outside of a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be like that but wasn't sure. Accepting and upvoting as soon as the system lets me.